# How was Mojo Jojo created?

Tags: powerpuff-girls

In the PowerPuff girls we know the girls were created from Sugar, and Spice, and everything Nice, plus the secret ingredient, chemical X.

[image]

What caused Mojo Jojo to turn from a normal monkey, into a super evil genius?

[image]

Comment: The bigger question is what was professor trying to make before Chemical X was added!! http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107542/is-there-an-explanation-of-what-would-have-been-created-without-chemical-x

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr he was trying to do what Rozen was doing in Rozen Maiden and create the perfect girl (Alice). unlike Rozen however when the Professor didn't get what he want he didn't pit the failures against one another saying for them to kill one another so the victor became the perfect girl

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Physically, a Chemical X explosion; psychologically, living rough and uncared for.

From the [Wikia page](http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/Mojo_Jojo) (emphasis mine):

> During the event of the creation of the Powerpuff Girls he pushed the Professor towards **a container of Chemical X, which caused an explosion, mutating his simian DNA, turning his skin green and causing his intelligence and brain to enlarge, growing out of his skull. It also gave him new emotions like envy and inferiority.**
>
> [...]
>
> After Blossom, Bubbles and Buttercup were created, the Professor lost interest and/or attention of Mojo's existence and forgot about him. With newfound intelligence, he donned a tattered overcoat with a partially shredded scarf and a paper bag to cover his brain and ran away, setting his home up in an alley. **Spending time on the street by himself with no one to care about him almost immediately turned him cold and emotionless** providing a motive as to why he would care to destroy Townsville and conquer the world.

References: the episode [Mr Mojo's Rising](http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Mojo%27s_Rising) and the film [The Powerpuff Girls Movie](http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Powerpuff_Girls_Movie).

Comment: Awww. I feel bad for Mojo Jojo :(

Answer (score 11):

> As seen in The Powerpuff Girls Movie and the episode "Mr. Mojo's
>   Rising", Mojo was originally Jojo, the Professor's hyperactive lab
>   assistant who always broke everything. During the event of the
>   creation of the Powerpuff Girls he pushed the Professor towards a
>   container of Chemical X, which caused an explosion, mutating his
>   simian DNA, turning his skin green and causing his intelligence and
>   brain to enlarge, growing out of his skull. It also gave him new
>   emotions like envy and inferiority.

[The Powerpuff Girls Wiki](http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/Mojo_Jojo)

Comment: ... why is there a Powerpuff Girls wiki?

Comment: @immibis Because there's a wiki for EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

When the Powerpuff Girls were made, he pushed the professor towards some Chemical X which caused it to spill into the recipe (giving the girls their superpowers) and explode causing Mojo to mutate and his skull and brain to grow. His skin turned green. Then, the Powerpuff Girls were born and they were Professor Utonium’s world. He loved Buttercup, Blossom, and Bubbles more than anything else and lost interest in poor Mojo. So, Mojo ran away and became evil.