# Is there an explanation of what would have been created without Chemical X?

Tags: powerpuff-girls

In the *PowerPuff Girls* we know the girls were created from "Sugar and Spice and everything Nice", plus the secret ingredient, Chemical X.

[image: Screenshot of man adding sugar, spices and everything nice]

**But Chemical X was never meant to be added the concoction!**

Have there been any episodes that explored what the Professor would have made if Chemical X had never been added?

Comment: Are you considering the nursery rhyme this is based on? "Sugar and spice,  And everything nice, That's what little girls are made of." Which would answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

The intro to the PowerPuff Girls.

> Sugar, spice, and everything nice
>
> These were the ingredients chosen
>
> **To create the perfect little girls**
>
> But Professor Utonium accidentally
>
> Added an extra ingredients to the concoction--
>
> Chemical X
>
> Thus, The Powerpuff Girls were born
>
> Using their ultra-super powers
>
> Blossom, Bubbles, and Buttercup
>
> Have dedicated their lives to fighting crime
>
> And the forces of evil

This opening statement is considered canon for the show, and the show acts on the assumption that everyone knows how the Powerpuff Girls were made. Only one episode has the Powerpuff Girls without Chemical X and it's a dream sequence.

> ["Oops, I Did It Again"](http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/Oops,_I_Did_It_Again) The Professor dreams he had made three normal little girls after realizing all of his successes are mere accidents.

[image: Beatrice, Bertha, and Betty]

Comment: That doesn't seem like it answers the question of what would have happened in any sort of canonical manner. Ideally, there would be some episode where they do a "For want of a nail" situation where they're just regular girls, but I know I don't know of anything of the sort.

Comment: the intro is cannon

Comment: Including the "You are dead" at the end?

Comment: @SeanDuggan i guess i should have watched the whole video.

Comment: There is also the episode where the girls play a game, race faster than light speed and go into the future where Him has won. Professor tried to recreate them in the meantime, but failed. There is also the episode with counterfeit powerpuff girls, with different levels of chemical X in them. And also when they created 4th sister Bunny who blew up in the end (because girls used what THEY considered to be everything nice). But, to my knowledge, there is no episode without chemical X.